What is the rigorous version of "If the partial derivative vanishes, then the function depends only on the other arguments"?
A paper that I'm reading says

Given $A(u,v)$, let us assume that $\frac{\partial A}{\partial u} = 0$. Then clearly $A(u,v) = A(v).$

I think this is ambiguous, and missing as many as several quantifiers.  I am attempting to construct a more explicit formulation. Here is my attempt:

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth, and let $U$ be an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$. If for some $v_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $u_0 \in U$, we have $\frac{\partial A}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0) = 0$, then there exists a constant $a_0$ such that $A(u,v_0) = a_0$ for all $u\in U$.

And maybe moreover,

If for some open ball $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $\frac{\partial A}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0) = 0$ for every $\langle u_0,v_0\rangle \in \Omega$, there exists a unique function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $A(u_0, v_0) = f(v_0)$ for all $\langle u_0,v_0\rangle \in \Omega$.

My questions are:

Is this statement correct? That is, have I inserted the correct quantifiers?
Is this statement an appropriate reformulation of the ambiguous statement from the paper, or is there a more natural interpretation?


I don't think you need smoothness, but only total differentiability. If you have it, you can take any point $v$ and show that the integral over the directional derivative in direction $u$ is always zero, so you get that $A(v,u')=A(v,u)$ for all$ u'$.  So your second statement looks correct.

@ConnFus I don't; just transposed the two variables on accident. Thanks, should be fixed now.


Let $A:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be partially differentiable in the first argument, and let $U$ be an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$. If for some $v_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $u_0 \in U$, we have $\frac{\partial A}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0) = 0$, then there exists a constant $a_0$ such that $A(u,v_0) = a_0$ for all $u\in U$.

The calculation is simple. For clarity define $a_0:=A(u_0,v_0)$ and $f(u):=A(u,v_0)$.  Then
$$
a_0=A(u_0,v_0)=f(u_0)=f(u_0)+f(u)-f(u)\underbrace{=}_{(1)} f(u)+\int_{u}^{u_0} f'(t)dt
=f(u)+\int_{u}^{u_0} \frac{\partial A}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0)
=f(u)=A(u,v_0)
$$
,where in (1) we used the fundamental theorem of calculus.
We also needn't $U$ be an open ball, just that $U\cap (ℝ\times \{v_0\})$ is connected.
The second statement then follows naturally.

The FTC is overkill here. The more elementary MVT is sufficient.

Both statements are correct, with slightly alleviated hypothesis: in the first one, smoothness is not required, not even continuity (only partial differentiability w.r.t. $u$ on $U\times\{v_0\}$, for some interval $U$), and in the second one, $\Omega$ neither needs to be a ball, nor to be open (only that each slice of it with $v$ fixed is an interval).
The second statement (with $f$ defined uniquely only on $\{v\mid(\exists u)\,(u,v)\in\Omega\}$) is then an immediate consequence of the first one, which can be rephrased more simply, letting $g(u)=A(u,v_0)$:

If $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is such that on some interval, $g'$ is defined and identically zero, then on that interval, $g$ is constant.

This is a corollary of the mean value theorem.
